# How to solve Magento 2 with composer 2 version error when sample data install

Tags: upgrade, composer, aws, sample-data, command

My application running AWS Bitnami platform. I am trying to upload sample data using composer after commands show warning message below

---

Do you want to store credentials for repo.magento.com in /bitnami/magento/var/composer_home/auth.json ? [Yn] y
Warning from https://repo.packagist.org: You are using an outdated version of Composer. Composer 2 is now available and you should upgrade. See https://getcomposer.org/2
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Warning from https://repo.packagist.org: You are using an outdated version of Composer. Composer 2 is now available and you should upgrade. See https://getcomposer.org/2
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.

---

Show above error.How can I solve this problem?
What is the best solution for this warning?
Can I Composer with continue version 1 or Upgrade with Version 2?
Thanks for advance for your reply

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure which m2 version are you using, but the [magento tech stack documentation](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/install-gde/system-requirements.html#composer) state that m2.4.2 is compatible with composer 1.x & 2.x, however, m2.4.1 is compatible with only composer 1.x. So upgrading composer while using 2.4.1 is a big no-no.

Even if you get this warning, this is unlikely that it's the reason why the installation failed.

Try adding the sample data by running the following commands:

```
bin/magento sampledata:deploy
```

```
bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

(Source https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/install-gde/install/sample-data-after-composer.html)

Good luck!

Comment: I am using magento 2.4.1 version and using composer 1 version.You mention installation failed.Website theme loading my custom theme. is this theme any relation problem with install sample data?

Comment: Could be, but i would have expected some more details in the displayed error :| nevertheless, don't upgrade composer of you are using m2.4.1.

Comment: Keeping composer 1 version.....I changed magento default theme luma...problem existing agian....I think problem from aws bitnami magento application

Comment: sorry to hear that! :(